# Camembert and histogram style

Tags: style, histogram

I want to know if there is a method for displaying camembert and histogram on map  using Openlayers3 and/or Geoserver. Like the picture bellow

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GeoServer has a [chart symbolizer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.13.1/extensions/geoserver-2.13.1-charts-plugin.zip/download) extension that can do this for you. GeoSolutions have a [detailed tutorial](https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/pretty_maps/charting.html)

You simply add a call to the `http://chart` endpoint in an `ExternalGraphic`.

```
<ExternalGraphic>
  <OnlineResource
    xlink:href="http://chart?cht=p&amp;chd=t:${100 * MALE / PERSONS},${100 * FEMALE / PERSONS}&amp;chf=bg,s,FFFFFF00" />
  <Format>application/chart</Format>
</ExternalGraphic>
```

To assist others looking for similar things the english term is "pie chart", though I think "camembert" is a much nicer name.